# #Selector as a parameter?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I want to create a function that adds a `refreshControll` to a `UITableView`.

The problem I have is the `#selector`:

```
extension UITableView{
    func refreshTableView(callFunction: #selector()){
        refreshControl = UIRefreshControl()
        refreshControl?.attributedTitle = NSAttributedString(string: "Pull to refresh")
        refreshControl?.addTarget(self, action: #selector(callFunction), for: .valueChanged)
        self.addSubview(refreshControl!)

    }  
}
```

I want to specify which function to call when I use this function.

Is this even possible?

Comment: You are asking how to declare a Selector as param for a func? Look at how is constructed `addTarget(_:action:for:)` that you use: `func addTarget(_ target: Any?, action: Selector, for controlEvents: UIControlEvents)`. So you should do `func refreshTableView(callFunction: Selector){`, and use it `action: callFunction`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`#selector(...)` is an expression of type `Selector`, so your method should accept a `Selector` object and pass it directly to the `action:` parameter.

```
extension UITableView {
    func refreshTableView(callFunction: Selector) {
        // ...
        refreshControl?.addTarget(self, action: callFunction, for: .valueChanged)
        // ...
    }
}

myTableView.refreshTableView(callFunction: #selector(whatever))
```

Comment: Thank you, I couldn't ctrl-click the #selector because Xcode is glitching.

Comment: `#selector` is a language keyword, I don't think that you can get anything meaningful from ctrl-clicking it anyway.